# Minimum number of commands to delete in order to stop a robot visiting all points of the lattice

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics

Suppose you place commands "turn left" or "turn right" in some points with integer coordinates (on a plane). Then, a robot is placed at $(0; 0)$. The robot begins to move in the positive direction of X-axis and when it gets into a point where a command is written it turns by $90^\circ$ and begins to move in the new direction. When it gets to a point with no command it just continues to move straight.

Suppose the commands are written so that the robot visits all points with integer coordinates.

Now, you can delete commands from points. The question is: can you always delete just one command so that the property "the robot visits all points" breaks? If not, what is the minimum number of points which should be tampered with to achieve this?

Any hints are welcome.

Comment: What if the commands make it so that the robot visits every point $100$ times. Clearly this is impossible, then.

Comment: It is easy to devise a set of commands st the robot visits all points, which can be broken by deleting a single command. But at the moment I cannot see an easy way to give a set of commands st the robot visits all points which is not broken by the deletion of a single command!

Comment: (1) There is only 1 command (or none) per point, right?  (In that case, I cannot quite see how a robot can visit a point more than 4 times without it being an infinite number of times.)  (2) What is the source of this problem?  It seems to me very fascinating & very hard at the same time...

Comment: What if it arrives back at the starting point? May commands be placed at $(0,0)$?

Comment: So it's an infinite plane, right?